# In Rider, how do I use an .sln file not in the project root folder?

Tags: msbuild, rider, sln-file

Our code is structured as:

```
- Readme.md
- deploy.sh
- infrastructure/
-- stacker.yml
-- ...
- backend/
-- backend.sln
-- ...
- frontend/
-- package.json
-- ...
```

The default behavior when opening a solution is for its folder-view to be rooted in the same folder as the .sln (`backend`, in this case).  Is it possible to either:

- change the root of the folder view, when starting from solution view?
- add solution views from nested folders, when starting from folder view?

Comment: Open Solution Explorer, select solution node, then add -> attach folder

Comment: Thanks @xtmq! That did it.

Comment: Well, I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open Solution Explorer
- Select solution node
- Invoke popup menu and invoke `Add` -> `Attach Folder`

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version i.e `JetBrains Rider 2022.3.3` do the following

- Open solution explorer
- Select solution node
- `Right click` -> `Add` -> `Existing Folder ...` (add the folder you want to attach)